# Example of a matrix where equality occurs for the relation between infinite and 2 norm

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces, examples-counterexamples, matrix-norms, spectral-norm

Given $A \in \mathbb R^{m\times n}$, I know that:

$$\|A\|_2 \le \sqrt {m} \|A\|_\infty$$ 
$$\|A\|_\infty \le \sqrt {n} \|A\|_2$$

I am supposed to provide an example of a matrix such that the equality holds. I tried diagonal first, to no avail, and can't seem to realize how to proceed as the $2$-norm would be tough to calculate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $$\|A\|_2 \le \sqrt {m} \|A\|_\infty$$  consider $$A=\begin{bmatrix}1&0&0&0\\1&0&0&0\\1&0&0&0\\1&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$$and for $$\|A\|_\infty \le \sqrt {n} \|A\|_2$$consider$$A=\begin{bmatrix}1&1&1&1\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}$$

**Hint**

For more general cases, consider $A=uv^T$ where $u$ and $v$ are $m\times 1$ and $n\times 1$ vectors respectively.

Comment: Oh, so basically we need a rank 1 matrix? What is the intuition behind that?

Comment: I don't think that rank-1 matrices are the only ones to satisfy the equality. I just started a simple general form (rank-1 form) and found some answers :) There might be  still some more matrices of ranks higher that 1....